# GroupBox control doesn't look the same on different OS versions

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a `WinForms` application that doesn't look the same way on different `OS` versions:

[image]

The fonts in the `GroupBox` control are the same in both cases (I'm using the same executable file, so there's no differences between controls at all).

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: increase the width of panel groupbox

Comment: @Anirudh So, how wide should it be then? Is there any guarantees that the new size will be enough for all Windows versions?

Comment: yes, just increase it for some more pixel

Comment: @Anirudh "For some more"? I don't want to trust this solution, mate, sry. Anyway, I want to know the actual reasons behind such behavior

Comment: windows 8 have different fontstyle and windows 7 , in ur code, the difference is of not more than 2 px just because of font style . so if u increase, it will solve the problem , for sure, just try it.

Comment: Which font you are using? `Segoe UI` is standard font for user interface.

Comment: @X-TECH Where is this information came from?

Comment: @FrozenHeart, see this behavior is not because of ur code, this is because of difference between windows 8 and windows 7. If you want to change then you have to increase ur width..

Comment: @Anirudh Ok, I changed it and now it looks the same, thanks a lot

Comment: @FrozenHeart have you researched on it?

Comment: @X-TECH No, just tried it